# Can't update from local, insecure repository

Tags: apt, 18.04, repository, software-sources

I'm trying to update a fresh 18.04 install from a local, insecure (no SSL inside corp network) repository hosted in artifactory. Usually I'd do:

```
 sudo apt-get --allow-unauthenticated update
```

but this still results in:

```
E: Failed to fetch [url of server] Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown. Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification [IP: ip  address].... etc etc
```

/etc/apt/sources.list is just one line. I also tried adding [trusted=yes] to the repo's line in sources.list.

I also tried creating an /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80ssl-exceptions file with:

```
Acquire::https::Verify-Peer "false"; 
Acquire::https::Verify-Host "false";
```

as in https://serverfault.com/questions/340887/using-a-self-signed-ssl-cert-for-an-https-based-internal-apt-repository

I still get the same error with any combination of these options. I can ping the repo's server, and can view the contents in a web browser. What am I doing wrong?